# What is a Date Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Date Word™** word.
Here is a list of Date™ and Not Date™ Words:

| Date Word™ | Not Date Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| SODA | COKE |
| FANDOM | SUPPORT |
| MADMAN | CRAZY |
| SOFA | COUCH |
| MOANS | CRIES |
| JAM | MARMALADE |
| DON | LORD |
| MAMAS | PAPAS |
| JAFA | CAKE |

CSV version:

```
Date Word™,Not Date Word™
SODA,COKE
FANDOM,SUPPORT
MADMAN,CRAZY
SOFA,COUCH
MOANS,CRIES
JAM,MARMALADE
DON,LORD
MAMAS,PAPAS
JAFA,CAKE
```

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Have you read our [guidelines](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5811/what-is-an-xyz-item-puzzles-what-not-to-do) for these sorts of puzzles? I've added the standard table and fixed your hyperlinks - you can look in the question's source text to see how.

Comment: Is the misspelling of [Jaffa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaffa_Cakes) intentional?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My answer

> A **Date Word** only contain letters used as the first letter of a month's name:
>  **J**anuary
>  **F**ebruary
>  **M**arch
>  **A**pril
>  **M**ay
>  **J**une
>  **J**uly
>  **A**ugust
>  **S**eptember
>  **O**ctober
>  **N**ovember
>  **D**ecember
>  J,F,M,A,M,J,J,A,S,O,N,D
>  Moreover, a letter from this list should be used only once per word.
>  A Not Date Word is not limited by those letters.